# Can the windows copy command affect the current instance of the file being copied?

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, ntfs

In my environment, I have an Excel VBA script assigning tasks and sending a 2 hour E-Mail report.

I also have a batch file that is using the "copy" command to simply copy the above Excel VBA script to a new location.

My exact question is: can copying that file affect the instance of the VBA script or any instance for that matter?

Batch file:

```
   @echo off 
:start
   copy "T:_ITS\Comm Help Desk\SomeFolder\Emails\Template\Automated Queue Development Testing\IQ v1.2.xlsm" "T:_ITS\Comm Help Desk\SomeFolder\Emails\IQ_Export\IQ_export.xlsm" /Y
   timeout /t 32 
   goto start
```

Comment: What is "my environment"? Is is special? What does your copy command look like? How do you only copy the macro without copying the Excel spreadsheet as a whole? What made you feel that copying has an impact? Is there any specific reason/problem why you ask this question? With all that questions open: yes, it might have a performance impact, because copying the file takes some time.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is in any way a programming question. It's not about the code in the batch file, and it's not about the code in the macro. What specific programming related question are you asking? Please [edit] to clarify; if you can't do so, then your question is probably better asked on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy a spreadsheet to an untrusted folder, Excel will prevent its macros from running.

Check out the Trust Center:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/view-my-options-and-settings-in-the-trust-center-HA010354326.aspx

Comment: But this would not affect the "running" original Excel file being copied? The reason I ask is that a batch file I have running is begin suspected as the trouble.

Comment: @user3612888: So the batch file runs concurrently with the macro's execution? In the batch file example you give, which of the .xlsm files is running?

Comment: Yes. The .xlsm being copied so the first one. The batch runs on one computer and the .xlsm being copied runs on another computer. Both files are on a network share.